# Why is GridView seeming to mix up different cells?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

My GridView is composed of views that have a Download button. The button hides when you tap it and displays a progress bar. The progress bar is updated by a Service that starts when the Download button is pressed.

The problem that I have is if I start a download for a particular element and then scroll down I notice that the progress bar is visible in cells that shouldn't be downloading. I think this is probably caused by GridView recycling cells, but I'm not entirely sure. I've posted some of the code below. I can post more if needed.

**getView - in Adapter for GridView**

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final RelativeLayout card;
            if (convertView == null) {
                card = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.book_cover, null);
            } else {
                card = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
            }
            TextView bookName = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.textView_bookName);
            TextView authorName = (TextView) card.findViewById(R.id.textView_bookAuthor);
            final MNBook currentBook = getItem(position);
                bookName.setText((String) currentBook.getTitle());
            authorName.setText((String) currentBook.getAuthor());
            final Button downloadBookButton = (Button) card.findViewById(R.id.button_download_book);
            final Button readBookButton = (Button) card.findViewById(R.id.button_read_book);
            final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) card.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_book_download);
            readBookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),
                                        currentBook.getFileName())),
                                "application/pdf");
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            downloadBookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    downloadFile(currentBook, progressBar,
                            downloadBookButton, readBookButton);
                }
            });
            if (currentBook.isBooleanDownloaded()) {
                downloadBookButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                readBookButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

//                ImageView bgImage = (ImageView) card.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
            Resources resources = getApplicationContext().getResources();
//                final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(mCategoryImages[position], "drawable",
//                        getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
//                bgImage.setImageResource(resourceId);
            return card;
        }
```

**downloadFile method**

```
private void downloadFile(MNBook book, final ProgressBar progressBar,
                              final Button downloadButton, final Button readButton) {
        final MNBook localBook = book;
        String fileName = book.getFileName();
        String url = book.getURL();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", url);
        intent.putExtra("file_name", fileName);
        intent.putExtra("receiver", new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
                super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
                if (resultCode == DownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {
                    int progress = resultData.getInt("progress");
//                    mDetailFragment.setProgress(progress);
//                            mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress);
                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                    if (progress == 100) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        readButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        setDownloadedBookStatus(localBook);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        downloadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        startService(intent);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update widget visibility on every `getView()` call, not just some of them. This is no different than needing to set the text or image on widgets on every `getView()` call. Widgets in `AdapterView` and `RecyclerView` classes, like `GridView`, get recycled. If you show the `ProgressBar` in one `getView()` call, and that widget gets recycled and you do not specifically hide it for the recycled `getView()` call, the `ProgressBar` will still be visible.